# How can I reproduce a logo?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am looking to reproduce this effect on an image in Adobe Photoshop.

[image]

Not the font or the word but the way it is outlined in white, does anyone know how I can do this?

Comment: you can probably do that with an outerglow style on that layer with an appropriate gradient. But, not programming related.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just select the text (ctrl+click on layer), expand selection border by ~5px, stroke.

Answer (score 6):

I think the following would be much better with Layer Styles:

1. Add a 5px outer stroke, and make it white.
2. Add a drop shadow. Use the spread and size sliders to adjust it until you're reasonably happy with the facsimile.

Comment: Provided the space between the outline and the letters is in fact white and not transparent.

Comment: You can adjust the size of the stroke to compensate for the spaces in letters. It would need to be adjusted relative to the size of the text anyways.